# Python: calculate sum of numbers csv file

Tags: python-3.x

In python: Starting from a csv file (contains 3 lines), how can I calculate the sum of all numbers in this file?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

total = 0
with open("file_with_three_lines.csv") as file:
   for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter=','):
        for col in row:
            total += int(col)
```

Something like this could work if you know there are only numbers in the file.